# Add a (double) variable to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I have a user input variable and i want to add that to an array. The firstStore is a BOOL type t determine if the array has been initialize. So the first time the STORE was called, it would initialize the array. I tried to make num equal to the operand (which is a double) by masking it NSNumber but that doesn't seem to work because i have this error "NSNumber may not respond to +operand", also the program crashes when it hits the line [memArray addObject:num]. I'm new at this stuff so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
else if ([operation isEqual:@"Store"]) {
    if(!firstStore){
        memArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSNumber *num = [NSNumber operand];
        [memArray addObject:num];
        firstStore = YES;
    } else {
         //NSNumber *num = [NSNumber operand];
        //[memArray addObject:num];
    }

}
```

Comment: tagging a question correctly will help to get some attention. xcode is just an IDE. for this question it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `[NSNumber operand]` to `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand]`.

Answer (score 2):

`"NSNumber may not respond to +operand"` means what is says: There is no such class-method `operand`. What was it supposed to do?

You dont need a bool to track if `memArray` is initialized. use:

```
if(!memArray)
```

or

```
if (memArray == nil)
```